# InstanceId#getId() doesn't return stable Id

Tags: android, google-play-services

According to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/iid/InstanceID) the InstanceId:

> provides a unique identifier for each app instance

and that the Instance ID is stable but may become invalid, if:

> - App deletes Instance ID
> - Device is factory reset
> - User uninstalls the app
> - User clears app data

However from my testing, it appears that the following call returns a different ID even if the app has only been swiped from the recents.

```
InstanceID.getInstance(context).getID();
```

Is this a bug in the Google Play Services or am I using it plain wrong?

Answer (score 2):

2 tymm answer: From Client library Instance ID code:

```
boolean needRefreshToken() {
        String appVersion = sSharedPreferencesHelper.get("appVersion");
        if (appVersion == null) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!appVersion.equals(sCurrentAppVersion)) {
            return true;
        }
        String lastTokenAcquiringTime = sSharedPreferencesHelper.get("lastToken");
        if (lastTokenAcquiringTime == null) {
            return true;
        }
        Long l = Long.parseLong(lastTokenAcquiringTime);
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000 - l <= 3600*24*7) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

About direct question: each Instance ID is backed by keypair stored in app preferences named "com.google.android.gms.appid"; 
 InstanceID.getInstance(context).getID() returns SHA-1 digest of public key in Base64 format. So try to investigate why it's impossible to restore KeyPair from preferences ;) 
Error is here inside library code (com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.class):

```
    KeyPair zzdj(String subtype) {
        String string2 = this.get(subtype, "|P|");
        String string3 = this.get(subtype, "|K|");
...
```

Should be:

```
KeyPair zzdj(String subtype) {
    String string2 = this.get(subtype + "|P|");
    String string3 = this.get(subtype + "|K|");
...
```

So, please get this IID from Registration Token (it's first part till colon) just after getToken(...) command. Because getID() initializes only "promise" KeyPair that will be used for next server request in case if your app were forcibly stopped from task bar which causes complete unload static variables.
Here is hot fix (please put it just before you call getId()):

```
public void fixPreferencesKeysId() {
    SharedPreferences sh = getSharedPreferences("com.google.android.gms.appid", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String privk = sh.getString("|K|", null);
    if (privk != null) {
        sh.edit().remove("|K|").putString("|S||K|", privk).commit();
    }
    String pubk = sh.getString("|P|", null);
    if (pubk != null) {
        sh.edit().remove("|P|").putString("|S||P|", pubk).commit();            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What they mean with *stable* is that the Instance ID will not become invalid without one of the events (App deletes Instance ID, ...) happening.

For example a GCM token is not stable in that regard since it can expire after some time and you need to check for that.